# TimeZone - getAvailableIDs() - filter only tzdb timezones

Tags: java, timezone

```
String[] available = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
```

The above piece of code in Java returns both TZDB format timezones and Windows format timezones. Is there a way to make it return just the TZDB timezones?  For example, some values it returns are,

AST 
America/Adak 
America/Anchorage 
America/Atka 
America/Boise PST
America/Los_Angeles...

I'm trying to eliminate AST, PST values in it..

Comment: In what way is PST a "Windows format" time zone? (Windows system time zone IDs are things like "Pacific Standard Time".)

Comment: Also note that TZDB contains time zones such as "EET" and "EST".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you should probably just filter out time zone IDs which don't have a `/` in. TZDB contains zone IDs such as EET and EST - for example, version 2014a contains the follow IDs of 4 characters or fewer:

> "CET", "Cuba", "EET", "EST", "Eire", "GB", "GMT", "GMT0", "HST", "Iran", "MET", "MST", "NZ", "PRC", "ROC", "ROK", "UCT", "UTC", "W-SU", "WET", "Zulu"

Filtering out anything that doesn't contain a `/` filters out a *little* bit more than that... it would remove all of:

> "CET", "CST6CDT", "Cuba", "EET", "EST", "EST5EDT", "Egypt", "Eire", "GB", "GB-Eire", "GMT", "GMT+0", "GMT-0", "GMT0", "Greenwich", "HST", "Hongkong", "Iceland", "Iran", "Israel", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Kwajalein", "Libya", "MET", "MST", "MST7MDT", "NZ", "NZ-CHAT", "Navajo", "PRC", "PST8PDT", "Poland", "Portugal", "ROC", "ROK", "Singapore", "Turkey", "UCT", "UTC", "Universal", "W-SU", "WET", "Zulu"

So check that list - if there's nothing in there that you mind losing, go with just filtering by `/`.
Note that almost *all* of the above are actually aliases for other IDs. Only the following are canonical IDs which don't contain `/`:

> "CET", "CST6CDT", "EET", "EST", "EST5EDT", "HST", "MET", "MST", "MST7MDT", "PST8PDT", "WET"

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. Just wanted to make sure, it wouldn't cut off something that's valid.