# Display a list of world timezones in flutter

Tags: flutter, timezone

I hate timezones, but this time I can't get by without them. I'm building an app with flutter that needs to preselect the user's timezone but still allow to change it. **What timezones should I display?**

After doing some research and looking at examples, I noticed 2 patterns

- display timezones as city names. Ex "America/Denver"
- display timezones as timezones. Ex "Mountain Standart Time"

I decided to go with the city name example because it was the easiest to code. This pattern is used in the "timezone" flutter package, iOS and Android devices, and returned when I query the user's timezone with the "flutter_native_timezone" package. This implementation, however, generated a lot of negative feedback from test users. Most people wanted to see Mountain Standard Time on the list. They also said if I'm using city names for timezones, I should pick the largest city if they share the same timezone. For example, America/Boise and America/Denver should not be displayed together because they're under Mountain Time and the largest should be included.

Can someone explain how I can solve this mess? Doing this manually is possible for 1 country, but doing this for all countries in the world is very tedious and error-prone. I would like to go with the timezone pattern, but this would require some sort of timezone resolution function that can take "America/Denver" and convert it to  "Mountain Standart Time" and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [canonical TZ database names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) for timezones.

Have you checked [timezone package](https://pub.dev/packages/timezone)?

This package provides the IANA time zone database and time zone aware DateTime class, TZDateTime.

They offer three different variants of the IANA database:

- default: doesn't contain deprecated and historical zones with some
  exceptions like "US/Eastern" and "Etc/UTC"; this is about 75% the
  size of the all database.
- all: contains all data from the IANA time zone database.
- 10y:default database truncated to contain historical data from 5
  years ago until 5 years in the future; this database is about 25% the
  size of the default database.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the timezone package, but it provides over 400 city names in the format of "America/Denver". I need to find a way to either trim it down to exclude cities under the same timezone like America/Denver and America Boise and only keep the larger city or convert it to a timezone like "Mountain Standart Time"

Comment: I would definitely try to implement canonical TZ database names for timezones. Can't help with implementation at the moment.

Comment: Canonical names would work great, but I need a way to filter out timezones that are useless. For example, America/Boise is a canonical timezone according to the Wikipedia article you shared; however, you will not find this timezone on an android device because America/Denver should be used instead.

Comment: does this thread help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26169888/timezone-getavailableids-filter-only-tzdb-timezones